# Find all $z\in\Bbb C$ such that $|z+1|+ |z-1|=4$

Tags: complex-numbers, conic-sections, absolute-value

I'd like to find all points of the complex plane which satisfy

$$|z+1| + |z-1| = 4. $$

I know this is an ellipsis with foci $1$ and $-1$, and I know that the answer is

$$3 x^2+4 y^2 \leq 12,$$

but I can't find a correct way of getting there.

First, I write $z$ as $x + i y$ and square both sides of the equation, then divide by 2 and get

$$x^2+y^2+1+\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2} \sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2} =8.$$

Pass $x^2+y^2+1$ to the RHS (right hand side), then

$$\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2} \sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2} =7-x^2-y^2.\tag{1} $$

Now, I would have to square both sides of the equation like this,

$$((x-1)^2+y^2)((x+1)^2+y^2) = (7-x^2-y^2)^2, \tag{2}$$

but the problem is that I cannot assure that the RHS is not negative, so there could be a value for $z$ such that (2) is satisfied but not (1), i.e it could exist $z=x + i y$ which satisfies

$$\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2} \sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2} =-(7-x^2-y^2)\tag{3} $$

in which case also satisfy (2) but not (1)!

So I would get an incorrect solution.

Comment: Try interpreting $|z-1|$ and $|z+1|$ geometrically on the complex plane, maybe it will be more intuitive for you.

Comment: It may be less messy if you subtract one of the terms on the left side from both sides before you square.

Comment: @ireallydonknow Didn't the OP already state that they know it's an ellipse?  That suggests a preexisting geometric interpretation.

Comment: Mathlove's answer is the most efficient way of doing this. Moreover, note that $z=2+0i$ and $z=-2+0i$ are easy solutions to this to pick off. These points should help you later with his hints.

Comment: @ErickWong Surely it's a form of geometric interpretation. However, is it the easiest one? I believe that comparing distances would be the easiest and most intuitive way of solving this question. The OP did not seem to have any idea on distances, IMO.

Comment: Regarding your confusion about the algebraic simplification, your comment "I cannot assure that the RHS is not negative."  In fact, it is always nonnegative, because if $x^2 + y^2 > 7$, then $|z| > \sqrt{7}$, and by the triangle inequality, $|z-1| + |z+1| \ge |(z-1) + (z+1)| = |2z| = 2|z| > 2\sqrt{7} > 4$.

Comment: thanks, heropup, at last someone answer my question.

Comment: This is one of the exercises in Bak/Newman's Complex Analysis, chapter 1.

Answer (score 4):

An ellipse is defined as the locus of all points,the sum of whose from two given points is constant. Here z is a complex number whose distance from $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$ is constant. Hence the locus of z is an ellipse *in the complex plane*. Hence z will be all those points which lies on the ellipse with focus $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that for $z=x+iy$, we have the following three equalities:
$$|z|^2 = x^2+y^2$$
$$|z+1|^2 = |z|^2+1 + 2x $$
$$|z-1|^2 = |z|^2+1 - 2x$$

Now, from the given equation we have:
$$|z+1| = 4-|z-1|$$
By squaring once, we get:
$$|z+1|^2 = 16+|z-1|^2 - 8|z-1|.$$
From the second and third equalities above, we get:
$$4x = 16-8|z-1|$$
Hence:
$$2|z-1| = 4-x$$
Squaring AGAIN:
$$4|z-1|^2 = (4-x)^2$$
Using the third equality:
$$4|z|^2+4-8x = (4-x)^2$$
Finally, using the first equality gives:
$$4(x^2+y^2)+4-8x = (4-x)^2,$$
from where we have:
$$3x^2+4y^2 = 12.$$

Answer (score 3):

HINT :

$|z-a|$ represents the distance between $z$ and a point $a$.

So, your equation represents that the sum of two distances is a constant.

You'll find a geometric way to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

I get the sense that you want an algebraic approach to transform the equation from the complex plane to Cartesian coordinates.  To this end, the key is to first square both sides:  $$\begin{align*} 16 &= (|z-1| + |z+1|)^2 \\ &= |z-1|^2 + 2|z-1||z+1| + |z+1|^2 \\ &= (x-1)^2 + y^2 + 2|z^2-1| + (x+1)^2 + y^2 \\ &= 2x^2 + 2 + 2y^2 + 2|(x+iy)^2 - 1| \\ &= 2\left(x^2 + y^2 + 1 + \sqrt{(x^2-y^2-1)^2 + (2xy)^2} \right). \end{align*}$$  Now dividing both sides by 2 and rearranging, we square again:  $$(8 - (x^2 + y^2 + 1))^2 = (x^2 - y^2 - 1)^2 + 4x^2 y^2.$$  Put all terms on one side and simplify:  $$\begin{align*} 0 &= (x^2-y^2-1)^2 - (x^2+y^2-7)^2 + 4x^2 y^2 \\ &= (-2y^2+6)(2x^2-8) + 4x^2 y^2 \\ &= -4(x^2-4)(y^2-3) + 4x^2 y^2 \\ &= 4(3x^2 + 4y^2 - 12). \end{align*} $$  This immediately gives the desired expression.  Note that the locus of points satisfying the **equality** is itself necessarily an equation, not an inequality:  the locus is the boundary of the ellipse, not its interior.

Comment: Yes, I want exactly what you say, but you did the same thing that I am saying is wrong! I mean the second squearing, because the RHS is not non negative for all z.

Comment: Please see the comment I just made in response to your original post.  I should also add that, even if you cannot assure that the RHS is always nonnegative, the worst that can happen when performing all these algebraic transformations is that you introduce extraneous solution sets.  In other words, the desired locus is always a subset of the solution set to the equation you obtain at the end.  It is up to you to determine whether any extraneous solutions were introduced during the squaring operations.

Answer (score 1):

As one comment suggested above, it is more efficient to 
subtract $|z-1|$ or $|z + 1 | $ from both sides first.

$$|z+1| + |z-1| = 4\\ \, \\
|z+ 1| = 4 - |z - 1 | \\ \, \\
|z+ 1|^2 = \left(4 - |z - 1 |\right)^2 \\ \, \\
|z+ 1|^2 = 16 - 8|z - 1 | + |z - 1 | ^2 \\ \, \\
|z+ 1|^2  - |z - 1 | ^2 = 16 - 8|z - 1 |  $$ Then let $z = x + iy$.
$$
|(x+iy) + 1|^2  - |(x+iy) - 1 | ^2 = 16 - 8|(x+iy) - 1 |  \\ \, \\
|(x+ 1) + iy|^2  - |(x-1) + iy | ^2 = 16 - 8|(x-1) + iy|  \\ \, \\
(x+1)^2 + y^2 - ( (x-1)^2 + y^2)  = 16 -8|(x-1) + iy| \\ \, \\
x^2 + 2x + 1 + y^2 -  (x-1)^2 - y^2  = 16 -8|(x-1) + iy|\\ \, \\
x^2 + 2x + 1 + y^2 - (x^2 -2x + 1) - y^2 =16 -8|(x-1) + iy| \\ \, \\
x^2 + 2x + 1 + y^2 -x^2 +2x - 1- y^2 =16 -8|(x-1) + iy|\\ \, \\
4x = 16 -8|(x-1) + iy|\\ \, \\
16-4x= 8|(x-1) + iy|\\ \, \\
4( 4 - x) = 8|(x-1) + iy|\\ \, \\
16( 4 - x)^2 = 64|(x-1) + iy|^2\\ \, \\
( 4 - x)^2 = \frac{64}{4} ( (x-1)^2 + y^2)\\ \, \\
16 -8x + x^2 = 4 (x-1)^2 +4y^2\\ \, \\
16 -8x + x^2 = 4x^2 -8x + 4  +4y^2\\ \, \\
16 = 3x^2 + 4y^2 + 4 \\ \, \\ 
3x^2 + 4y^2 = 12
$$ This is an equation of ellipse.

Answer (score 0):

As others have hinted, you can look at it geometrically. Equation:

$$ | z - 1 | + | z + 1 | = 4 $$

states that the sum of two distances is equal to 4. This is something suspiciously similar to an ellipse definition:

> In mathematics, an ellipse is a plane curve surrounding two **focal points**, such that for all points on the curve, **the sum of the two distances to the focal points is a constant**. 
>  *[Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse]*

We can read the *focal points* from our equation. They are: $ F_1(1, 0) $ and: $ F_2(-1,0) $, respectively.

---

If you want to draw an ellipse, you need to compute $ a $ and $ b $.

Let's first compute $ a $. Consider the point $ (a, 0) $. Since the $ y $ component of this complex number is zero, we can only focus on the $ x $ axis:

$$ (a + 1) + (a - 1) = 4 $$
$$ 2a = 4 $$
$$ a = 2 $$

We can make use of [linear eccentricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_(mathematics)#:%7E:text=The%20linear%20eccentricity%20of%20an,either%20of%20its%20two%20foci.) to compute $ b $:

$$ a^2 = c^2 + b^2 $$
$$ b = \sqrt {a^2 - c^2} $$
$$ b = \sqrt {2^2 - 1^2} $$
$$ b = \sqrt {3} $$

Thus, we have the equation of an ellipse:

$$ \frac {x^2} {2^2}  + \frac {y^2} {\sqrt{3}^2} = 1 $$